# Can I apply generic type parameter overloading to classes?

Tags: typescript

When using functions in TypeScript, developers can specify overloaded type parameters like so:

```js
type Foo = {
  <T0> (a: T0): void
  <T0, T1> (a: T0, b: T1): void
  <T0, T1, T2> (a: T0, b: T1, c: T2): void
}

const foo: Foo = (...args: any[]) => { }
```

Is such a think possible for classes?

The following is illegal, but I am attempting to force the parameters of the `Foo.bar` method to be the values supplied in the generic parameters.

```js
type Foo = {
  <T0> new () => { bar(a: T0): void }
  <T0, T1> new () => { bar(a: T0, b: T1): void }
  <T0, T1, T3> new () => { bar(a: T0, b: T1, c: T2): void }
}

const Foo: Foo = class {
  bar(...args: any[]) {}
}

const foo = new Foo<string, number>()
foo.bar('hi', 42)
```

I know I can use a tuple to specify the arguments:

```js
class Foo<T extends Array<any>> {
  bar(...args: T) {}
}

const foo = new Foo<[string, number]>()
```

But I'd prefer not to specify my type arguments in the form of a tuple. Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is:

```
type Foo = {
    new <T0>(): { bar(a: T0): void }
    new <T0, T1>(): { bar(a: T0, b: T1): void }
    new <T0, T1, T2>(): { bar(a: T0, b: T1, c: T2): void }
}
```

It's almost as if there were a method named `new`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKCjqA7CAdygB4AVABgD4AKASgC40oAjAQwCca2nLGoAbnACWAEygBfLLnxFSlADRQyARlr9UrTt14UlLXiv5Cxk6bgLFye5SqVkATOqab2XHspsHbSgMa8HYxFxKUxQrF84PABnYFgEJnhEFF8AGzZo6LRzHDcaADpCzgBzaKY2PBAAbQBdOmZQ8MxImLiAMwRkWWIkkliOYTxipTwAVwBbFggOdSwOuHy8gHIAC2ElpQAWQKggA)